# Angular $asyncValidators transferring error code to template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement an Angular asynchronous validation. The basic works, but I fail to understand how to pass validation result from controller to my template.

My HTTP/post call going through my PHP Laravel server works. The handler to process my response too. What I do not understand it is how to pass "success/fail" status from the controller to my template. The pending status works fine, but how to display en OK/FAIL message ???

Question: what is the right pattern to pass the OK/Fail status from an asynchronous validation to template ?

Here after my controller and template. Note that OPACFG is out of scope, it is a constant that I use to pass information from Laravel to Angular.

My controller

```
   app.directive ('myValidationWithBackend', ['OPACFG', '$http','$q', function(OPACFG, $http, $q) {
    result= {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                var handler = $http.post('check-device', {_token: OPACFG.token, username: value});
                handler.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log ("handler ok");
                    $q.reject ('hoops');
                });
                handler.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log ("handler err");
                    return true;
                });
                return handler;
            };
        }
    }; return result; } ]);
```

My Template

```
 <div   ng-controller="NewDeviceCtrl">
    <div class="errors">
          <ul>
          <li>xxxxxx</li>
          <li data-ng-show="myForm.val1.$error.required">Value missing in val1</li>
          <li data-ng-show="myForm.val2.$error.myValidationDataError">Invalid val2 should start with 'A'</li>
          <li data-ng-show="myForm.val3.$error.????">Invalid val3</li>
          <li data-ng-show="myForm.val3.$pending">Waiting val 3 response</li>

          </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- Form name used for valid nd-model for data association in controller -->
   <form novalidate name="myForm"ng-submit="submitForm(myForm.$valid)" >
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="form._token">
        <input type="text" name="val1" ng-model="form.val1" required>
        <input type="text" name="val2" ng-model="form.val2" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" required my-validation-data-input>
        <input type="text" name="val3" ng-model="form.val3" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" required my-validation-with-backend>
      <button type="submit" class="sucess button small" >DoIt</button>
     </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: I find out a working option, but I'm not sure about it. If I do a "ngModel.$setValidity(elem.name, true/false)" within handler.sucess/error methods then it works.  In this case I do not use $q.reject. Question to the Angular experts, is this a valid option ? is so why no one use it in samples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using $asyncValidators $q.reject doesn't actually do anything to .$error, it instead makes myForm.username.$invalid:true and myForm.username.$invalid:false. While myForm.username.$pending exists neither $invalid or $valid exists.
So you should be able to keep using $q.reject and in your html put..

```
 <li data-ng-show="myForm.username.$invalid">Invalid val3</li>
```

That make sense? I can go into more detail if you need.

Comment: I would lie if I was responding that it is clear to me ;) If I understand your point $q.reject will set myForm.xxxxxxxx.$invalid in my template. In this case what is the parameter of reject for ? I checked angular doc at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q but I must have miss something as I fail to understand the global logic.

Comment: I've seen the parameter of reject is used for throwing errors, but I'm really not sure. I used this guide to get my head around all the asyncValidators stuff; http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Comment: I did not find for reject parameter, but without anything it work. Doing a $q.reject() when validation fail and a simple return true; otherwise is doing the job.